# Clustering with max cluster size

Tags: algorithm, optimization, cluster-analysis, partitioning

I have a set of n nodes, which have a certain weight w associated with them. Moreover I have a matrix which stores the differences between each pair of these points.

What I want to achieve is to partition these nodes into a fixed size of groups so that the distance is minimal. As an additional constraint each group has a certain capacity associated which is equal for each group, so that the sum of the weights of nodes belonging to this group can`t be greater than this capacity.

I did some research on this but found only papers like [this one](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/268292668_Clustering_with_Size_Constraints) which only lead to equally many point in each cluster not with the addition of weights of each point.

My question is, is there an algorithm which solves this problem?

Comment: for the additional capacity constraint, is there one capacity for all groups? If no, do you know how many clustering groups you will have and how do you identify these groups? apart from that, for me, this sounds like a problem which could be solved using LP/QP. e.g. min distances with constraint sum(w_i,g) <= capacity_g and a cluster assignment function

Comment: I.e., basically capacitated facility location.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively to modeling this as a Linear Programming problem, look for "Graph Cutting Measures" to create "balanced partitions", and look for algorithms that maximize "Modularity". These are a field of active academic research. According to the paper by Parthasarathy and Faisal (Ch. 17 in the textbook by Aggarwal and Reddy "Data Clustering, Algorithms and Applications") optimizing any of these objective functions is NP-hard (especially with additional constraints such as yours).

Answer (score 1):

A possible approach is to follow the same principle as K-means, while ensuring that the constraints are satisfied. To do so, you have to iterate between steps 2-3:

1. Assign data points to clusters (randomly)
2. Compute the centroid of each cluster
3. Assign points to the clusters, such that:

   - The total sum of squared distances of points to the centroids is minimized
   - Sum of weights of nodes in each cluster does not exceed the capacity

This algorithm is guaranteed to improve at each step. However, like k-means, it converges to local optima. The main difference with K-means is that step 3 in K-means is a simple operation that can be performed in O(n), while the step 3 in your case is an NP-complete optimization problem. However, depending on the dataset, chances are that this problem can be solved in reasonable time.

I have a python [implementation](https://github.com/Behrouz-Babaki/MinSizeKmeans#constrained-k-means-with-weighted-instances) of this algorithm. You can try it on your data and see if this works for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *clustering*, have a look at **index bulk loading strategies**.

Clustering is usually concerned with *structuring* the data set.

Disk-oriented indexes usually have a block size to fulfill. On a 8k page, you can only store 8k of data, so you need to split your data set into chunks of this maximum size.

Also look at **DIANA**. This classic clustering algorithm is a top-down approach. It starts with the complete data set, and repeatedly splits it. You could use this and continue splitting until the desired maximum cluster size is achieved.